# iOS Dev on El Capitan Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan

I'm just starting to learn iOS development. I have an old macbook pro that is running El Capitan (10.11.6). I was reading that the last version of Xcode that would be compatible is 8.2. If there is a later version that will work fine, let me know.

What are the drawbacks of developing in 8.2 as apposed to 9.2, the most recent version? am I going to face any major issues if I develop on 8.2?

Thanks in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest drawback is probably that you won't have access to the iOS 11 SDK which ships with Xcode 9. That means that you won't be able to use any functionality that is new to iOS 11 in your application. If you're using Swift, you also won't get the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will face language issue because Xcode 8.2 support Swift 2.3 while Xcode 9.2 support latest swift 4.0
2. Xcode 9 includes SDKs for iOS 11.2, watchOS 4.2, macOS 10.13.2, and tvOS 11.2
3. Xcode 9.2 having iPhone x simulator (new device)

You face issues while migrating to latest one.

Answer (score 0):

If your macbook spec is not fast enough latest xcode will make u suffer. also latest xcode requires MacOSX High Sierra too. However just for comparison, my Mac Mini 2012 runs "ok ish" on Mac High Sierra and XCode 9.2. So if your macbook spec is similar to mine then you ought to use latest one.